# Error Accessing Collection [Excel VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I'm having trouble with collections in VBA. I'm getting a "Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument" error.

Here is my code:

```
Public c As Collection    
Public Sub imageRows()

        Set c = New Collection

        Set masterBook = ActiveWorkbook
        Set ds = masterBook.Sheets("Sheet4")

        'Getting Image URLS
        For Each sku In ds.Range("AF2:AF7") 'data sheet
            'c.Add "Data1", "Key1"
            rNum = sku.Row

            'Adding Image URLs
            c.Add ds.Range("BF" & rNum).Value, sku & "-" & 1
            c.Add ds.Range("BG" & rNum).Value, sku & "-" & 2
            c.Add ds.Range("BH" & rNum).Value, sku & "-" & 3
            c.Add ds.Range("BI" & rNum).Value, sku & "-" & 4
            c.Add ds.Range("BJ" & rNum).Value, sku & "-" & 5

            MsgBox c.Item(sku & "-" & 4) '=========THIS WORKS
        Next sku

        Set bs = masterBook.Sheets("Sheet5") 'bulk upload sheet
        'Inserting Rows
        'Getting Image URLS
        For Each sku In bs.Range("N3:N9") 'data sheet
            'c.Add "Data1", "Key1"
            MsgBox sku.Value '======WORKS, GIVES VALID VALUE
            MsgBox c.Item(sku & "-" & 4) '========THIS CRASHES

        Next sku


End Sub
```

The program always crashes the second time I try to access the collection. I thought it was a scope issue, but I made the collection global and it still happens.

Please assist.

Comment: What line does the debugger show you when the error occurs?

Comment: should you be using `MsgBox c.Item(sku.Value & "-" & 4)`?

Comment: The values in bs.Range(N3:N9) aren't the same as as in ds.Range(AF2:AF7). They might look the same, but they're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen if the key you use to access an item **does not** exist (I mean: refers to no item)

### An example:

```
Public c As Collection
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Set c = New Collection

    c.Add "sentence1", "key1"
    Debug.Print c.Item(1)            ' Prints  "sentence1"
    Debug.Print c.Item("key1")       ' Prints  "sentence1"
    Debug.Print c.Item("keyThatDoesntExist")    ' FAILS ! Run-time error 5

End Sub
```

### To conclude:

So I imagine you get the `Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument` because `sku & "-" & 4` is not a valid key of `c` and refers to nothing.
It's the exact same problem I have with `Debug.Print c.Item("keyThatDoesntExist")`

@Dick Kusleika sums up well the point in his comment: 
"*The values in `bs.Range(N3:N9)` aren't the same as as in `ds.Range(AF2:AF7)`. They might look the same, but they're not.*  "

[Run-time error 5 on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445484%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

> An argument probably exceeds the range of permitted values

Comment: Thank you. The values look the same and have been trimmed, does it have to do with the way it is stored?

Comment: @CHawk look the same an are the same? or different? Actually I don't know how they are stored exactly ... For the value in the cells the exact value may not be the one displayed depending on the display options (precision etc...) Not sure I got your comment well